# How to remove XmlRootElement wrapper while marshalling in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

Lets say I have the following POJO class, which I want to marshal using JAXB

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
Class Employee {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private int age;
}
```

Now I am marshaling an instance of Employee class using following code snippet

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\employee.xml")
marshaller.marshal(employee, os);
```

The generated XML looks like

```
<Employee>
  <firstName>Mark</firstName>
  <lastName>Smith</lastName>
  <age>30</age>
</Employee>
```

Question : I don't want the default Employee tag around employee data.
i.e.

I want output as following

```
 <firstName>Mark</firstName>
  <lastName>Smith</lastName>
  <age>30</age>
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you asking. XML document must contain root element.
You can change it using QName (example below), but it must exist.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
QName qName = new QName("", "whatever");
JAXBElement<Employee> newRootEmployee = new JAXBElement<Employee>(qName, Employee.class, employee);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\employee.xml")
marshaller.marshal(newRootEmployee , os);
```